# loading the content after click yensdesign tabbed menu

Tags: jquery, menu, tabbed

I've used this tutorial:
http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/create-a-smooth-tabbed-menu-in-jquery/

it is yensdesign tabbed menu. Could sb tell me how do I have to change the code to load content of particular tab after clicking on this tab?

Answer (score 0):

Working with the [js](http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/tabs/tabs.js), you want to change each case to something like:

```
case 'news':
  $('#news').load('/fetch-content?tab=news', function() {
    $("#news").addClass("active");
    $("#tutorials").removeClass("active");
    // .. etc ..
  });
```

There are loads of variations on this - maybe you want to make the tab active before loading the content go give the user immediate feedback in case your server takes a few seconds to respond.

Also, the addClass/removeClass stuff in the `tabs.js` file doesn't scale too well.  It'd be better to select all divs, then filter out the ones you're not interested in, e.g.:

```
$('#tabs > div').filter(':not(#news)').removeClass('active');
```

(something like that anyway)